# How to select time in dropdown of datepicker (Selenium & Python)

Tags: python, selenium, datepicker, selenium-chromedriver

I want the script to select a specific time on the start time drop down.

I am using Selenium Chromedriver with Python for https://www.sailbox.ch/de/bootliste . I managed to open the drop down of the start time picker (hour:minutes). 
I tried several ways to place the click on the value 22:00.

This is the setup

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.sailbox.ch/de/bootliste")
assert "sailbox" in driver.title
```

This opens the drop down of the start time date picker

```
driver.find_element_by_id("filterFormInput_timeFrom").click()
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
```

Then I tried multiple options:

Option 1

```
start_time = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='xdsoft_time']//div[@data- 
hour='22'][@data-minute='00']")
driver.implicitly_wait(4)
start_time.click()
```

Option 2

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[@class='xdsoft_time' and text()='20:00']")
```

Option 3

```
driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[@data-hour='22'] and [@data-minute='00']")).click();
```

Currently, I get the error that 'the element is not clickable'. 
the goal is to select the value "22:00" from the drop down.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it turns out that this website runs `jQuery`. Knowing that you can simply  do:

```
driver.execute_script('$("#timeFrom").val("22:00").change();');
```

which would change your input to the desired time

Comment: Perfect, that helped a lot! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath to select the time, it works for both from and to times.

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'xdsoft_datetimepicker')][starts-with(@style,'display: block')]//div[.='22:00']
```

**Screenshot:**
[image]